# iOS Core Data - Double to Decimal Migration Issue

Tags: ios, core-data-migration

I have gone through my data model and have converted a number of properties from double to decimal.  I am trying to do the default migration process, and continue to get error: "Can't find mapping model for migration".

I have used mapping models in the past, and been able to do the lightweight migration using them, as I have typically only had structure changes.

This is the first time, I am doing a conversion of one type: NSNumber to another type: NSDecimalNumber.

Reading the docs, it seems like I need to use subclasses of NSEntityMigrationPolicy, which I have created.  However still getting the same error with not finding the mapping model.

Are there some gotchas I'm not seeing with keeping the column name the same, and changing the type of the value that prevents the mapping model from getting found?

Comment: Have you added the correct flag when you create the model? Something like     NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption,
                             @{@"journal_mode": @"delete"}, NSSQLitePragmasOption, nil];
`

Comment: I have these datastore options set:     _dataStoreOptions = @{ NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES };  -- I provide my own mapping models.  Have done this over several versions of my schema, and it seems to work until now.

Comment: I have setup a simple project with one Entity and one attribute - first mapped as a double, and then converted to decimal.  Migration works without any special effort, i.e. no NSEntityMigrationPolicy required for converting from NSNumber to NSDecimalNumber.  Looks like I have some other issue with my migration.

Comment: I did the same, changed some attribute types in a demo project and everything worked as expected. Did yoh generate a new NSManagedObject Subclass? It could be that it is trying the old subclass on the new model. That'll fail.

Comment: Figured it out.  I was a dunderhead.  I had made changes to the previous schema version file between release builds of my app.  I restored the previous schema version file, rebuilt my mapping models, and Bob's your uncle, things work as expected.